# Using magellan-nightwatch, is there a way to assert some element is hidden / displayed?

Tags: nightwatch.js, magellan, magellan-nightwatch

`waitForElementPresent` or `waitForElementNotPresent` probably won't work if the element is not showing on the screen by one of `display: none`, `visible: hidden` or `opacity: 0`.

(it should be similar to jasmine-jquery's expecting an element `toBeHidden()`. )

Answer (score 1):

use `.waitForElementVisible` or `.waitForElementNotVisible` to see if it is displayed or hidden